# Why is Chrome breaking this layout?

Tags: css, google-chrome

See http://www.arthwine.co.uk.

This used to work fine in Chrome and works fine in all other browsers (afaik). Now, for some reason, Chrome is hiding most of the left column (apart from the bear). If you look on a different browser, there is a panel with the branding and a menu in it under the bear.

I can't figure out at all why it's doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it in Chrome 9.0.597.98 and I had the same problem. The solution that I found, is to add `position:absolute;` for the `#header`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. Any idea why that works? I'd never have tried that.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it breaks is because of the bear. Or rather, it is because of the way you relatively positions the image of the bear outside the bounds of every single one of it's parent elements except the body.

This makes chromes rendering engine choke on your layout somehow.

You can test this very easily by just deleting the image of the bear from the source code, and see how everything else suddenly pops into place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in Chrome. I see the menu and the branding.

Comment: Very strange. I've tested this on two computers (WinXP and MacOS) and it doesn't work in Chrome. Works fine on my MacBook though. What version of Chrome do you have?

Comment: 10.0.648.45 dev so it might be something in Chrome that they have fixed.